# ANTLR is too tolerant for the equals sign

Tags: typescript, antlr, antlr4, dsl

I have a pretty basic ANTLR configuration to parse expressions. It can parse things like `12 + myVariable.myAttribute == myResult(myParameter)`. However it seems to be a bit too tolerant when it comes to the `=` sign at operators. For example it will not find any errors when writing `1 += 2`, even though I did not specify the `+=` operator. The same goes for `1 !== 2` or `1 and= 2`. It's as if the first `=` which would make the operator invalid after an otherwise valid operator is just completely ignored. What am I doing wrong?

My configuration ([complete repository on Github](https://github.com/peternoordijk/rivia/tree/master/src/compiler/grammar/parser)):

```
grammar MyGrammar;

/*
 * Parser rules
 */

expression: operation ( ( operator operation)*) EOF;

operation: operationWithBrackets | operationWithoutBrackets;

operationWithBrackets:
    '(' operation (( operator operation)*) ')';

operationWithoutBrackets: primitive ( ( operator operation)*);

primitive: string | bool | number | nil | variable;

string: SINGLE_STRING | DOUBLE_STRING;

nil: NIL;
bool: BOOLEAN;
param: operation;

variable:
    variablePart (
        (
            ( '.' variablePart)
            | ( '[' bracketOperation ']')
            | ( callStart ( param ( ( ',' param)*))? callEnd)
        )*
    );

callStart: '(';
callEnd: ')';

variablePart: VARIABLE_PART;
bracketOperation: operation;

number: NUMBER;

operator: OPERATOR;

/*
 * Lexer rules
 */
OPERATOR:
    '+'
    | '-'
    | '/'
    | '*'
    | '=='
    | '!='
    | '<='
    | '>='
    | '<'
    | '>'
    | 'and'
    | 'or'
    | 'then'
    | 'else';

SINGLE_STRING: '\'' ~('\'')* '\'';

DOUBLE_STRING: '"' ~('"')* '"';

NUMBER: '-'? [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?;

WHITE_SPACE: [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;

IF: 'if' -> skip;

BOOLEAN: 'true' | 'false';
NIL: 'null';

VARIABLE_DOT_SEPARATOR: '.';

VARIABLE_PART: ([a-zA-Z0-9] | '\\.' | '-' | '_')+;
```

Comment: When I run your grammar on the input `1 !=== 2`, I get a "token recognition error at: '= '".

Comment: Yes that's because you added two `=` signs. (I expect it to fail already at `!==`.) It ignores the first `=`, but not the second

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in my comment. I ran it on the input `1 !== 2`. On the input `1 !=== 2` I actually get a parse error, not a token recognition error (because `==` is a valid token in your grammar).

Comment: Okay... That makes sense I guess. However it doesn't explain why it doesn't fail for `1 !== 2`...

Comment: To be clear: Both inputs produce errors for me (running your grammar with grun using the Java target). `1 !== 2` produces a token recognition error and `1 !=== 2` produces a syntax error.

Comment: Ohh that's very strange... That would mean it's related to the typescript variant of antlr4. I'm using antlr4ts. Thanks for pointing it out though!

Comment: It could also mean that you're getting the error as well, but you don't realize it. Note that error listeners only listen for syntax errors, so token recognition errors would only end up in the console and not call your listener if you registered one. That's also why it's generally recommended to add a catch-all rule to your lexer (like `INVALID: .;`) to make it impossible to get token recognition errors.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thank you so much for the info! I will read into this

Comment: A catch-all rule is not necessary at all. Just register an own error listener in both lexer and parser and you will get notified for all syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sepp2k has pointed out in the comments above this was a lexer error which wasn't recognised correctly.